# Does the /3gb switch reduces the User Objects Limitation?

Tags: windows

Windows has a limitation of 10000 USer Objects. If we reach this limitation, an exception is thrown.
If I use the /3gb switch, this limitation is less than 10000 objects? (meaning that the out of memory exception will be thrown with less than 10000 user objects?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it affects the user objects limit in any way, that limit is not enforced by memory limitation, but by some code in user32.dll. You can raise the user objects limit up to 18000 following the [trick 3 of this page](http://apo-phil.org/?p=63).
By the way, do not ever use the /3GB switch unless you really know what it does and you are aware of its drawbacks: it doesn't provide any advantages to applications compiled without the /LARGEADDRESSAWARE linker switch, and squeezes the OS in just 1 GB of address space, which can result in several problems. Read [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/22/218527.aspx) to understand better what that switch does and what problems arise when it's used.